# How do I extract a file/folder_name only from a path?

Tags: r, stringr

Unfortunately I suck at regexp. If I have a path like so:

`/long/path/to/file`, I just need to extact `file`.

If someone supplies `file/` I just need `file`.

If someone supplies `/file/`, I still need just `file`.

I've been using `stringr` functions as a crutch but this seems like straight up `grep` territory. Help, please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could use the `basename` function.

```
f <- "/long/path/to/file"
basename(f)
# [1] "file"
```

Comment: A more elegant solution and it also takes care of trailing slashes. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
> path <- "/long/path/to/file"
> require(stringr)
> str_extract(path, "[^/]*$")
[1] "file"
```

Comment: What if I need to lose the trailing slash as well?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for giving an answer to a very old question, but I was led here searching for a way to extract only the *directory* part of a full filename.

So here is, how you extract the directory:

```
> f <- "/long/path/to/file"
> dirname(f)
[1] "/long/path/to"
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried:

```
dirname(f)
```

I got the stunningly unhelpful return of "."  So, I tried:

```
z <- getwd()
```

which returned the path to the working directory as a character string, which at least in my current use case is actually useful.