# R: extract directory out of a path

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I extract a file/folder_name only from a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693877/how-do-i-extract-a-file-folder-name-only-from-a-path)

May I ask you how I can get the last subdirectory of a path.
For example I want to get the subdirectory "7" and the following code fails:

```
Path <- "123\\456\\7"
Split <- strsplit(Path, "\\") # Fails because of 'Trailing backslash'
LastElement <- c[[1]][length(Split[[1]])]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could also use the built-in function `basename`:

```
basename(Path)
[1] "7"
```

Comment: Interesting that this currently has almost 2x the up-votes compared to the same answer in the previous question (7 vs 4)...

Answer (score 5):

You have to add a second pair of `\\` to escape the `\` to the regex:

```
> Path <- "123\\456\\7"
> Split <- strsplit(Path, "\\\\")
> Split[[1]][length(Split[[1]])]
[1] "7"
```